# DNS queries timeout, despite getting an answer

Tags: dns

We're getting DNS timeouts on Windows 7 enterprise machines.

When using nslookup, we're getting a message along the lines of "no reply for 2 seconds, server timeout"... but that's not true. I have ran packet captures at the same time, and we can see the DNS query going through, AND the DNS reply coming back.

Additionally, it says "timeout after 2 seconds" despite timing out after less than 300ms.

It should be noted that we use a dns-suffix. So if you query google.com, it's first querying google.com.suffix.com for the A record, then for the AAAA record, then it'll try google.com.

Nonetheless, all of this happens really fast and we do get replies, but somehow they're not accepted by the PC. It happens with nslookup but also with the machine as a whole, and nothing works anymore. It's also completely random - sometimes it happens, sometimes not.

I have seen in one of my packet capture an ICMP message "port unreachable" from the DNS server to the host. I have read somewhere that it might suggest there are no UDP sockets opened, but don't know much what I could do with this information.

What else could it be ?